# grub-efi-amd64 on ovh serwer

Tags: grub

This is ovh server.

```
    root@ns302572:/home/saltworks/panel.saltworks# sudo apt-get install libvirt-daemon
```

result

```
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done

 
   After this operation, 120 MB of additional disk space will be used.
    Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
    Get:1 http://ubuntu.mirrors.ovh.net/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 fontconfig amd64 2.12.6-0ubuntu2 [169 kB]
.....
    Fetched 30.7 MB in 6s (5,459 kB/s)    
    Extracting templates from packages: 100%
    Selecting previously unselected package fontconfig.
    (Reading database ... 82156 files and directories currently installed.)
    Preparing to unpack .../000-fontconfig_2.12.6-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
    Unpacking fontconfig (2.12.6-0ubuntu2) ...
.....
    Setting up grub-efi-amd64-signed (1.187.3~18.04.1+2.06-2ubuntu14.1) ...
    Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
    grub-install: error: cannot find EFI directory.
    dpkg: error processing package grub-efi-amd64-signed (--configure):
     installed grub-efi-amd64-signed package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
    Setting up libopus0:amd64 (1.1.2-1ubuntu1) ...

    Setting up libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:amd64 (1.14.5-0ubuntu1~18.04.3) ...
    Setting up libcairo2:amd64 (1.15.10-2ubuntu0.1) ...
    Setting up libtag1v5:amd64 (1.11.1+dfsg.1-0.2build2) ...
    Setting up libspice-server1:amd64 (0.14.0-1ubuntu2.5) ...
    Setting up dconf-service (0.26.0-2ubuntu3) ...
    Setting up libv4l-0:amd64 (1.14.2-1) ...
    Setting up libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:amd64 (2.36.11-2) ...
    Setting up libcairo-gobject2:amd64 (1.15.10-2ubuntu0.1) ...
    Setting up libaugeas0:amd64 (1.10.1-2ubuntu1) ...
    Setting up libflac8:amd64 (1.3.2-1ubuntu0.1) ...
    Setting up libgdk-pixbuf2.0-bin (2.36.11-2) ...
    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of shim-signed:
     shim-signed depends on grub-efi-amd64-signed (>= 1.187.2~) | grub-efi-arm64-signed (>= 1.187.2~); however:
      Package grub-efi-amd64-signed is not configured yet.
      Package grub-efi-arm64-signed is not installed.
    
    dpkg: error processing package shim-signed (--configure):
     dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
    No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                              Setting up libnss3:amd64 (2:3.35-2ubuntu2.16) ...
    Setting up libharfbuzz0b:amd64 (1.7.2-1ubuntu1) ...
    Setting up libthai0:amd64 (0.1.27-2) ...
    Setting up librdmacm1:amd64 (17.1-1ubuntu0.2) ...
    Setting up librados2 (12.2.13-0ubuntu0.18.04.11) ...
    Setting up ibverbs-providers:amd64 (17.1-1ubuntu0.2) ...
    Setting up libpango-1.0-0:amd64 (1.40.14-1ubuntu0.1) ...
    Setting up libcacard0:amd64 (1:2.5.0-3) ...
    Setting up libjack-jackd2-0:amd64 (1.9.12~dfsg-2) ...
    Setting up libavahi-common3:amd64 (0.7-3.1ubuntu1.3) ...
    Setting up libvorbisenc2:amd64 (1.3.5-4.2) ...
    Setting up libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0:amd64 (1.14.5-0ubuntu1~18.04.3) ...
    Setting up libtheora0:amd64 (1.1.1+dfsg.1-14) ...
    Setting up libshout3:amd64 (2.4.1-2build1) ...
    Setting up dconf-gsettings-backend:amd64 (0.26.0-2ubuntu3) ...
    Setting up gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:amd64 (1.14.5-0ubuntu1~18.04.3) ...
    Setting up gsettings-desktop-schemas (3.28.0-1ubuntu1) ...
    Setting up libnetcf1:amd64 (1:0.2.8-1ubuntu2) ...
    Setting up librbd1 (12.2.13-0ubuntu0.18.04.11) ...
    Setting up qemu-block-extra:amd64 (1:2.11+dfsg-1ubuntu7.42) ...
    Setting up qemu-utils (1:2.11+dfsg-1ubuntu7.42) ...
    Setting up libpangoft2-1.0-0:amd64 (1.40.14-1ubuntu0.1) ...
    Setting up libsndfile1:amd64 (1.0.28-4ubuntu0.18.04.2) ...
    Setting up libavahi-client3:amd64 (0.7-3.1ubuntu1.3) ...
    Setting up qemu-system-common (1:2.11+dfsg-1ubuntu7.42) ...
    Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/qemu-kvm.service → /lib/systemd/system/qemu-kvm.service.
    Setting up libvirt0:amd64 (4.0.0-1ubuntu8.21) ...
    Setting up libpangocairo-1.0-0:amd64 (1.40.14-1ubuntu0.1) ...
    Setting up libpulse0:amd64 (1:11.1-1ubuntu7.11) ...
    Setting up libvirt-daemon (4.0.0-1ubuntu8.21) ...
    Setting up gstreamer1.0-x:amd64 (1.14.5-0ubuntu1~18.04.3) ...
    Setting up libvirt-daemon-driver-storage-rbd (4.0.0-1ubuntu8.21) ...
    Setting up libsdl1.2debian:amd64 (1.2.15+dfsg2-0.1ubuntu0.2) ...
    Setting up qemu-system-x86 (1:2.11+dfsg-1ubuntu7.42) ...
    Setting up qemu-kvm (1:2.11+dfsg-1ubuntu7.42) ...
    Processing triggers for systemd (237-3ubuntu10.57) ...
    Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
    Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-21) ...
    Processing triggers for install-info (6.5.0.dfsg.1-2) ...
    Processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:amd64 (2.56.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.9) ...
    Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1.6) ...
    Setting up glib-networking:amd64 (2.56.0-1ubuntu0.1) ...
    Setting up libsoup2.4-1:amd64 (2.62.1-1ubuntu0.4) ...
    Setting up gstreamer1.0-plugins-good:amd64 (1.14.5-0ubuntu1~18.04.3) ...
    Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1.6) ...
    Errors were encountered while processing:
     grub-efi-amd64-signed
     shim-signed
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

root@ns302572:/home/saltworks/panel.saltworks# systemctl status libvirtd

```
    Unit libvirtd.service could not be found.
    root@ns302572:/home/saltworks/panel.saltworks# ^C
    root@ns302572:/home/saltworks/panel.saltworks# ^C
    root@ns302572:/home/saltworks/panel.saltworks# 
    root@ns302572:/home/saltworks/panel.saltworks#
```

root@ns302572:/home/saltworks/panel.saltworks# sudo dpkg --configure -a

```
    Setting up grub-efi-amd64-signed (1.187.3~18.04.1+2.06-2ubuntu14.1) ...
    Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
    grub-install: error: cannot find EFI directory.
    dpkg: error processing package grub-efi-amd64-signed (--configure):
     installed grub-efi-amd64-signed package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of shim-signed:
     shim-signed depends on grub-efi-amd64-signed (>= 1.187.2~) | grub-efi-arm64-signed (>= 1.187.2~); however:
      Package grub-efi-amd64-signed is not configured yet.
      Package grub-efi-arm64-signed is not installed.
    
    dpkg: error processing package shim-signed (--configure):
     dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
    Errors were encountered while processing:
     grub-efi-amd64-signed
     shim-signed
    root@ns302572:/home/saltworks/panel.saltworks# sudo apt-get install -f
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
    2 not fully installed or removed.
    After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
    Setting up grub-efi-amd64-signed (1.187.3~18.04.1+2.06-2ubuntu14.1) ...
    Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
    grub-install: error: cannot find EFI directory.
    dpkg: error processing package grub-efi-amd64-signed (--configure):
     installed grub-efi-amd64-signed package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of shim-signed:
     shim-signed depends on grub-efi-amd64-signed (>= 1.187.2~) | grub-efi-arm64-signed (>= 1.187.2~); however:
      Package grub-efi-amd64-signed is not configured yet.
      Package grub-efi-arm64-signed is not installed.
    
    dpkg: error processing package shim-signed (--configure):
     dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
    No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
     grub-efi-amd64-signed
     shim-signed
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

root@ns302572:/home/saltworks/panel.saltworks# ls /sys/firmware/efi

```
    ls: cannot access '/sys/firmware/efi': No such file or directory
```

root@ns302572:/home/saltworks/panel.saltworks# sudo apt-get remove grub-efi-amd64-signed shim-signed

```
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    The following packages will be REMOVED:
      grub-efi-amd64-signed shim-signed
    WARNING: The following essential packages will be removed.
    This should NOT be done unless you know exactly what you are doing!
      shim-signed grub-efi-amd64-signed (due to shim-signed)
    0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
    2 not fully installed or removed.
    After this operation, 12.0 MB disk space will be freed.
    You are about to do something potentially harmful.
    To continue type in the phrase 'Yes, do as I say!'
     ?] ^C
    root@ns302572:/home/saltworks/panel.saltworks#
```

what is happen ? how to fix it ?

UPDATE 1

```
root@ns302572:/home/saltworks# apt install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up grub-efi-amd64-signed (1.187.3~18.04.1+2.06-2ubuntu14.1) ...

Installing for x86_64-efi platform..............................................................................................................................................................................................] 
grub-install: error: cannot find EFI directory.
dpkg: error processing package grub-efi-amd64-signed (--configure):
 installed grub-efi-amd64-signed package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of shim-signed:
 shim-signed depends on grub-efi-amd64-signed (>= 1.187.2~) | grub-efi-arm64-signed (>= 1.187.2~); however:
  Package grub-efi-amd64-signed is not configured yet.
  Package grub-efi-arm64-signed is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package shim-signed (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 grub-efi-amd64-signed
 shim-signed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I don't want to uninstall; I wanted to reinstall. I have no idea what is causing the issues. The server has been running for many years. An "apt upgrade" was performed, and now, as you can see, nothing is working.

Comment: try `apt install -f`

Comment: can you format your question in such a way that it isn't a wall of output where the commands you ran are not easily distinguishable from the output they produced! Also, why are you trying to remove essential packages?